# How to escape { and } in the Svelte REPL?

Tags: svelte

I am using the [Svelte REPL](https://svelte.dev/examples#hello-world) and would like to render a code block:

```
<pre>
function () &#123;
// test
&#125;
</pre>
```

Is there a more convenient way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
{@html `<pre>function (){//test}</pre>`}
```